# Javascript recursive nested comparison loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion, lodash

I'm trying to create a recursive function that loops through an config object, which contains keys that must be set, this is compared to an `appConfig` later on, which must match all the keys (nested) inside the `unsetConfig`

```js
const _ = window._
const UNSET_CONFIG_VAR = 'UNSET'

let config = {
  logging: {
    hasConsole: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    hasSyslog: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    processName: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    inner: {
      test: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR
    }
  }
}

const unsetConfig = _.clone(config)

function initialize (appConfig) {
  const walkConfig = (currentConfigLevel, previousPaths = []) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(currentConfigLevel)) {
      if (_.isObject(value)) {
        previousPaths.push(key)
        walkConfig(currentConfigLevel[key], previousPaths)
      }

      const path = previousPaths.length !== 0 ? previousPaths.join('.') : key

      if (!_.get(appConfig, path)) {
        throw new Error(`Config was missing: ${path}`)
      }
    }
  }

  walkConfig(unsetConfig)
}

initialize({
  logging: {
    hasConsole: true,
    hasSyslog: true,
    processName: true,
    inner: {
      as: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The expected output would be that an error would be thrown, as you can see in the `initialize` function the `test` key is missing in `logging.inner`.

But no error is thrown.

I've tried it in a different setups now but I'm kinda stuck on this.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code. I suggest that you learn how to use the developer tools in Google, Firefox, or whatever browser you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wish to check the existence of a value from a certain path then you only need to use [`lodash#has`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has). Using `lodash#get` will get the value of a specific property from a certain path, but using such value to check the existence of such path isn't reliable since the value can be a falsy value.

Additionally, the path argument accepted by both `lodash#has` and [`lodash#get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) accepts either a string or an array, so you actually don't need to join them from a separator. In fact, joining this in such a manner fails when one of your config property contains an array. Since the array key notation is encased in a bracket e.g. `[0]` or `[1]`.

```
function initialize(appConfig) {

  const walkConfig = (config, paths = []) => {
    Object.entries(config).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let $paths = paths.concat(key);

      if(!_.has(appConfig, $paths)) {
        throw new Error(`Config was missing: ${$paths.join('.')}`);
      }

      if(_.isObject(value)) {
        walkConfig(value, $paths);
      }
    });
  };

  walkConfig(unsetConfig);

}
```

```js
const { _ } = window;
const UNSET_CONFIG_VAR = 'UNSET'

let config = {
  logging: {
    hasConsole: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    hasSyslog: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    processName: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR,
    inner: {
      test: UNSET_CONFIG_VAR
    }
  }
}

const unsetConfig = _.cloneDeep(config); // Clone inner objects as well

function initialize(appConfig) {
  
  const walkConfig = (config, paths = []) => {
    Object.entries(config).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let $paths = paths.concat(key);
      
      if(!_.has(appConfig, $paths)) {
        throw new Error(`Config was missing: ${$paths.join('.')}`);
      }
      
      if(_.isObject(value)) {
        walkConfig(value, $paths);
      }
    });
  };
  
  walkConfig(unsetConfig);
  
}

initialize({
  logging: {
    hasConsole: false,
    hasSyslog: true,
    processName: true,
    inner: {
      as: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Error: Config was missing: logging.hasConsole.hasSyslog` - fail?

Comment: I'd also swap the order of `if(_.isObject(value)) {` and `if(!_.has(appConfig, $paths)) {` - to get the right error message :p

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the error message is correct as what the OP mentioned: `The expected output would be that an error would be thrown, as you can see in the initialize function the test key is missing in logging.inner.`

Comment: yes, but try putting `Inner: { as: true}` or even `Inner: {test: true}` instead of `inner: {as:true}` in the object being passed to initialize  ... sure, the error is "correct" in a way, but the fact is that `inner` is the non-existent property

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm changing it right now :)

Comment: I think between us we've answered it well :p I'll remove my answer, it's basically redundant :p